# How can i make shortcuts to applications in desktop in Ubuntu GNOME?

Tags: gnome, desktop, icons, ubuntu-14.04

I am using **Ubuntu 14.04 GNOME**. I find it difficult to start an app by pushing the mouse pointer to the top edge. Is it possible to create shortcut icon in **desktop** just like windows icons?
If so , what should i do?

Answer (score 1):

Use [Create launcher](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/create-launcher/) from Ubuntu repository for creating custom launchers. you can install the same from commandline also. from terminal type

`sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends gnome-panel`.

you can open launcher from terminal by this command

`gnome-desktop-item-edit ~/Desktop/ --create-new`

The other method is

```
Right click on the file
Click on `Make Link`
A link will be created 
Move the link to desktop
```